# Disable expanding after doubleclick

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Is there any way I can disable expanding TreeNode after doubleclick??

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is no simple way to achieve this, as far as I know. One thought would be to have a `bool` variable set to `true` on the DoubleClick event, and use the `e.Cancel` property of the `BeforeExpand` event to prevent the node from expanding. However, those two events are fired in the opposite order, so that is not a solution. I don't have another solution from the top of my head; will update if I come up with one.

**Update**

I have played around with this a bit, and I have found one way that works *reasonably* well. As I have mentioned the problem is that `BeforeExpand` happens *before* `DoubleClick`, so we can't set any state in `DoubleClick` to use in `BeforeExpand`.

We can, however, detect (potential) double clicks in another way: by measuring the time between `MouseDown` events. If we get two `MouseDown` events within the time period that defines a double click (as stated in [`SystemInformation.DoubleClickTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.doubleclicktime.aspx)), it should be a double click, right? And the `MouseDown` event is raised before `BeforeExpand`. So, the following code works rather well:

```
private bool _preventExpand = false;
private DateTime _lastMouseDown = DateTime.Now;

private void treeView1_BeforeExpand(object sender, TreeViewCancelEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = _preventExpand;
    _preventExpand  = false;
}

private void treeView1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    int delta = (int)DateTime.Now.Subtract(_lastMouseDown).TotalMilliseconds;            
    _preventExpand = (delta < SystemInformation.DoubleClickTime);
    _lastMouseDown = DateTime.Now;
}
```

I say "rather well" because I feel that it prevents the node from expanding in some cases when it should not (for instance if you within the double click time click first on the node text and then on the plus sign). That might be possible to solve in some way, or perhaps you can live with that.

Comment: Actually, there is a very simple way of achieving this.

Comment: @baeltazor: I tried out the solution you suggest in your answer prior to posting my answer. See my comments under your answer.

Comment: In the MouseDown event, you check to see if the Location of the click is within a few pixels (maybe 3-5) in the X-Y directions of the last MouseDown location. If so, and the MouseDowns are within the threshold, it's a double-click.

Comment: Great answer, BTW. Helped me solve an issue where certain nodes should open a child window when double-clicked, even though they may have children.

Comment: @KeithS: good addition. As is happens, there is a definition of that distance too: [SystemInformation.DoubleClickSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.doubleclicksize.aspx).

Comment: Checking time and pixel deltas between mouse down events, becomes obsolete when using the ``Clicks`` property of the ``MouseEventArgs`` passed to the ``MouseDown`` event handler. This property seems to be set according to the system's double click configuration.

Answer (score 27):

```
private bool isDoubleClick = false;

private void treeView1_BeforeCollapse(object sender, TreeViewCancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (isDoubleClick && e.Action == TreeViewAction.Collapse)
        e.Cancel = true;
}

private void treeView1_BeforeExpand(object sender, TreeViewCancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (isDoubleClick && e.Action == TreeViewAction.Expand)
        e.Cancel = true;
}

private void treeView1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    isDoubleClick = e.Clicks > 1;
}
```

You can declare a private field isDoubleClick and set various TreeView events as above. This will prevent expand/collapse TreeView node on double click. However expand/collapse will work via + and - icons.

Comment: You can take a boolean variable like:

private bool blnDoubleClick = false;

and set various treeview events as follows. This will prevent expand/collapse treeview node on double click.
However expand/collapse will work via + and - icons.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as it does not rely on knowing the doubleclick timings

Comment: I agree this should be the excepted answer. Worked flawlessly and super simple to implement.

Comment: Needs one further adjustment, suggest setting isDoubleClick = false before exiting the BeforeCollapse and BeforeExpand event handlers.  Solution as written has the side effect of suppressing expand/collapse via the keyboard (right/left arrow keys) if you had earlier double-clicked on the control.

Answer (score 5):

A MouseDown event will occur before the BeforeExpand/BeforeCollapse events. You can check the Clicks property of the MouseEventArg to distinguish between a double-click and a single click:

```
bool dblClick;

private void treeView_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  dblClick = e.Button == MouseButtons.Left && e.Clicks == 2;
}

private void treeView_BeforeExpand(object sender, TreeViewCancelEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Action == TreeViewAction.Expand) e.Cancel = dblClick;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Handles the event BeforeExpand and set the property Cancel of event args object to true.

```
private void OnBeforeExpand(object sender, TreeViewCancelEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```

The TreeViewCancelEventArgs contains also the affected node and the action that caused the event so you can implement a more sophisticated logic to enable or disable the expand behavior than my simple example.

Comment: Hi,
Unfortunately I don`t see action (like doubleclick or simple expand) in TreViewCancelEventArgs

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can do this.

Somewhere by itself in the code write this:

```
bool CanExpand = true;
```

... and inside the doubleclicked handler write this:

```
CanExpand = false;
```

.......and inside the um.. the BeforeExpand event, type this:

```
if( CanExpand )
   Application.DoEvents();
else e.Cancel = true;
```

I hope this has helped.

---

I just tested this, and it works flawlessly. :-) Below is the whole code that I used to test it. So you can see how it works:

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        bool CanExpand = true;

        private void treeView1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CanExpand = false;
        }

        private void treeView1_BeforeExpand(object sender, TreeViewCancelEventArgs e)
        {
            if (CanExpand)
                Application.DoEvents();
            else
                e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I just tried this out and it shows a *very* inconsistent behavior (it allows the first expand on doubleclick, since `BeforeExpand` is raised before `DoubleClick`, then it blocks the next expand attempt, regardless of how it is triggered). Also, your code should probably set `CanExpand = true` last in the `BeforeExpand` event handler, or it will block all future expand attempts.

Answer (score 1):

I know this thread is quite old, but had the same issue now and found alternate solution. I'm not sure if `treeView_blockInfo_NodeMouseDoubleClick` was available at the time this thread was opened, but my solution is to attach this event and use this piece of code:

```
private void treeView_blockInfo_NodeMouseDoubleClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
{
    if (!e.Node.IsExpanded)
    {
        e.Node.Expand();
    }
    else
    {
        e.Node.Collapse();
    }
}
```

Works for me (though I was not testing this to depth). The only problem I can think of is that it might cause flickering.

Comment: this actually is not dsiabling expanding but rather collapse the node back after expand

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution:

```
int treeX;   // somewhere in class scope

// Add a MouseMove event handler
private void treeView1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    treeX = e.X;
}

// Add a BeforeExpand event handler
private void treeView1_BeforeExpand(object sender, TreeViewCancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (treeX > e.Node.Bounds.Left) e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid, this would prevent expanding everytime the mouse is over the node (in fact, since you're only checking the x coordinate, it might also happen, when the mouse is over any other node...). Expansion shoul only be prevented in case of double clicks according to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the point of view. 
Instead of disabling expanding on doubleclick, you can allow expanding only when the user clicks on the [+] button.

This way, you can use the GetHitTestInfoAt method, and allow the expansion only if the clicked element is htOnButton.
The following code works for Delphi 6:

```
procedure Form1.TreeView1Expanding(Sender: TObject; Node: TTreeNode; var AllowExpansion: Boolean);
var
   p:Tpoint;
   ht:THitTests;
begin
p:=Mouse.CursorPos;
ht:=treeview1.GetHitTestInfoAt(treeview1.ScreenToClient(p).x,treeview1.screentoclient(p).y);
AllowExpansion:=(htOnButton in ht);
end;
```

Answer (score -2):

Simplest way:

```
treeList.OptionsBehavior.AllowExpandOnDblClick = false;
```

Comment: This solution doesn't apply to a Winforms treelist.  I think [this](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraTreeListTreeList_OptionsBehaviortopic) control is what the author of this answer used.